# Java web applet/form reverse engineering

Tags: java, web-applications, reverse-engineering

I'm supposed to create a new product based on a discontinued product. The problem is the original programmers of the discontinued product lost the source code (yeah, awesome).

The software is run through a web browser. When I go to their url, a window pops up with the title "Oracle Developer Forms Runtime". I'm not sure if this is an applet or Java plugin or whatever, because I've only been developing Java "command line" applications.

Is there any luck I can see what's being called and returned between the app and the server so I can imitate something similar? If so, what tools should I be looking into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given my knowledge of Oracle Forms (which is quite limited by the way), Peter Tillemans's answer is in the right direction. The applet is merely a thick-client for the screens built in Oracle Forms.

If you want to recover the source code, you'll need to look for the *.fmb files (the Forms Builder files that contain the source code) built for the application. These would contain the PL/SQL source code as well as the screen layout, and would have to be opened using the Oracle Forms Builder tool. You might also want to acquire a copy of any PL/SQL source code that is meant to run on the database server.

If you've lost the FMB files, then you might have to figure out a way to recover the sources from the compiled FMX files, that is actually used at runtime by the Forms Server. I'm not aware of any decompilers for these.

In my opinion, decompiling the applet is an exercise in futility, for that is a part of the Oracle Forms Java client (and is part of the Oracle Forms product itself), meant to be deployed on a web server. None of the screens developed as part of the application, are actually compiled into Java classes; the applet actually performs the job of receiving UI information from the Oracle Forms Server and displaying it on the screen. It is the Forms Server where the heavy lifting occurs; all business logic and transaction management occurs in this server, and this is what you should be after (and it can be found in the FMB and FMX files).

There are other files that might also need to be accounted for.

- PLL files would contain PL/SQL source code that is in use across multiple forms.
- MMB files would contain menu modules.

Comment: I'm using debian linux and the chrome browser. I've been poking around to find the cache and also trying to see the network traffic but couldn't find the fmx files. I thought they should be cached somewhere on my machine. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Russell, yes. The Forms architecture looks [like this](http://doc.xmarc.net/xmarc6/es/Fire/fug/webforms.htm). The applet only does the job of rendering the UI. Everything else occurs on the server, because of the nature of Forms apps.

Comment: @Russell, to add more salient points - when Oracle brought out the concept of browser-delivery for Forms applications, they had no choice but to use an applet. Traditional Forms applications could simply not be exposed over a HTML-based UI. That's because the product is more or less a two-tier product, and it continues to be one despite the ability to use a browser. The Forms server, does quite a lot of work that requires the presence of a stateful connection between the client and the database server. Contd.

Comment: The applet merely makes this process asynchronous by not requiring that a connection to the database be maintained at all times, from the traditional Forms runtime (on the user's desktop) to the database server. In other words, state (and transaction) management between the middleware (if you can call it) and the database server, is performed by the Forms Runtime. Business logic may execute on the runtime (via the FMX files) or on the database server.

Comment: Thanks Vineet. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Typed a bit of contradictory stuff up there. My first statement in the previous comment should read as: "The applet merely makes this process asynchronous by not requiring that a connection to the database be maintained from the user's desktop, as is the case for traditional Forms applications."

Comment: @Russell, you're welcome. I would like to point out that porting the code line by line might be difficult, for Forms is a rich-client. You can define triggers on UI events at various levels in the screens, and have transactional updates performed on the database at the same time. Quite obviously, this is not easily achievable with a thin client web-app. You will be spending quite some time in understanding the business needs, to map them into achievable requirements for the web-app. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with a Oracle Forms application. The "applet" is basically a fat-client application which talks to an Oracle application backend.

You are going to need the Oracle Forms toolset.

More information can be found in the [Forms FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Forms_FAQ)

Answer (score 0):

There are many decompilers out there that might give you a good head start on this project.  http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&q=java+decompiler

Comment: For an oracle forms applet? I think it would be easier if he start from scratch.